# mariaDB not use openssl fips library

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, mariadb, fips, mariadb-10.1

I'm trying to use openSSL fips library in **mariadb 10.1.45 community version** on **Ubuntu 18.04.6** server and I can't do it.

I have installed on my server the **1.1.1-1ubuntu2.fips.2.1~18.04.3.1** version of openssl package and also enable the fips mode in kernel (file /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled has number 1 inside it) however when I check the variable **version_ssl_library** into mariadb  I get **OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017** as result.

Originally I installed the mariadb-server package from mariadb repository and then I build and install mariadb following this instructions (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/building-mariadb-on-ubuntu/) but I have the same result

I just read mariadb documentation (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/tls-and-cryptography-libraries-used-by-mariadb/) and undestand that mariadb not necessary use the last version of openssl installed in server and is fine for me but how I have to configure it to use fips library? community version of maridb allows you to use openssl fips library?

Comment: Note that unless legally or contractually required to comply to FIPS, you generally do not want to use this mode. It will make things much more complicated and in many cases even less secure than what you would have with the "standard" mode as FIPS often requires older or restricted cryptographic modes.

Comment: Hi @HolgerJust. Thanks for your answer and I agree with you but unfortunately I have to use it because is contractually requiered. do you know how to use this mode?

Comment: There is an open task to [support FIPS mode better](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20260) with an ongoing recent discussion.